# Handle Two UI threads in WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a UI which will take some time to load say 1 minute or more. Now i need to show opacity and progress bar in background to give the affect that something is in progress. As we know that two UI threads can't work simultaneously so I created a new thread to run progress bar

```
  private void ShowProgressBar()
        {
            DialogProgress dialogProgress = new DialogProgress("ATAM Desktop", "Loading module...");
            dialogProgress.Show();
        }



 thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
 thread.Start();
```

now at the end i need to close the progress bar i.e. after 1 minute.
While using

> thread.abort

method sometimes it abort the process and sometime it take some time (Not a reliable solution).
Another way is that declare DialogProgress class object global and at the end close the window.
Still its showing error,

> "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different
>   thread owns it"

Anyone please help me with best solution to my problem.

Comment: Search for async await progress, you will find all you can handle

Comment: Googling Backgroung worker in c# wpf

Comment: Background worker process will not update the progress bar status.

Comment: Please never ever call `Thread.Abort()` unless you are trying to crash out of your entire app. Aborting threads can put the run-time in an undefined state which can cause anything to happen.

Comment: Also, you can't have two UI threads. Period. So you can't create a second thread with any UI elements in it.

Comment: @Enigmativity that's not true - you can have multiple UI threads, each with their own controls.

Comment: @Evk - I thought that wasn't possible without separate AppDomains?

Comment: @Enigmativity you just need to start new STA thread and start message loop there (via `Dispatcher.Run()` or analog in winforms) - that's all that makes thread "UI" thread. Of course one UI thread cannot really interact with another (like you cannot "host" one control inside control in another thread), they are completely separate - so usually you host only top-level container (window\form) in such separate UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it like this. Create some variable for your dialog:

```
private DialogProgress _dialogProgress;
```

Then start a thread and assign that variable:

```
var thread = new Thread(() => {
    _dialogProgress = new DialogProgress();
    _dialogProgress.Closed += (sender, args) => {
        // when window is closed - shutdown dispatcher
        _dialogProgress.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
    };
    _dialogProgress.Show();
    // run dispatcher (message pump) on this thread
    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
});
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
```

Then when you are done, close window like this:

```
_dialogProgress.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => _dialogProgress.Close());
```

`_dialogProgrses.Dispatcher` will give you access to the dispatcher of that other thread you created, so `_dialogProgress.Close()` will be invoked on correct UI thread. After window is closed, handler we setup in a thread will shutdown dispatcher of that thread, and the whole thread will end gracefully, without any aborting.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: This seems to be perfect solution for my problem. but while applied above solution i found n exception                                                           An unhandled exception of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll

Additional information: A task was canceled.

Comment: @Praveensharma this code by itself should not cause such exception. To help us solve it you need to post updated code and full exception stack trace.

Comment: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233029
  Message=A task was canceled.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:

Answer (score 0):

> This is how I find solution to my problem.

```
    DialogProgress dialogProgress = null;
    private void ShowProgressBar()
    {
        dialogProgress = new DialogProgress("ATAM Desktop", "Loading module...");
        dialogProgress.Show();
    }

    private void LoadProgressBar(Thread thread)
    {
        lock (lockProcessStart)
        {
            if (dialogProgress == null)
            {
                LayoutRoot.Opacity = 0.9;
                LayoutRoot.Refresh();
                thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                thread.Start();
            }
        }
    }

    private void UnloadProgressBar(Thread thread, bool isSave = false)
    {
        lock (lockProcessStart)
        {
            if (dialogProgress != null)
                Dispatcher.FromThread(thread).Invoke(new Action(() => dialogProgress.Close()));
            dialogProgress = null;
            if (isSave)
                LayoutRoot.Opacity = 1;
        }

    }
```